# how to pass data in data layer Magento 2.1

Tags: magento, magento2.1

I've created Google Analytics and Google Tag Manager account to find out all event of product like Add to Cart, Remove Cart, Checkout, Product click, Checkout, Product impression in Google Analytics.

I've created Tag and Trigger for that but its not reflecting in Google Anaytics.

> First I want to display data layer in front end with all products
>   details...

Please tell me how to pass data in data layer. **is i have to code in core file** to get product `id`, `name`, `price`, etc. and pass variable on `datapush` script as mentioned on this url: [Enhanced Ecommerce (UA) Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce). Or Magento have default functionality for this. only paste the script on header file??? to get datalayer in frontend with details.

Answer (score 1):

**For Magento 2 EE**, you can do it without any extensions or code modification. Check the documentation instructions for setting up a Google Tag Manager account, configuring your Magento store, and creating a tag.

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/google-tag-manager.html

Or you can use a third-party extension like the following,..

**For Magento 2 CE**, you will need a third-party extension to setup GTM. Mageplaza has made [a list of the best extensions](https://www.mageplaza.com/review/google-tag-manager/) in 2018 in the market.

If you don't want to use any extensions to install & configure GTM. You can insert the tags and tracking codes in phtml blocks & overrides. [More info about that](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116943/add-google-tag-manager-to-magento-2).